# How to Post An Image On pinterest from an android app?

Tags: android, integration, sharing, pinterest, social-media

I want to share a bitmap image in social media.
I can share images with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn etc., but I could not find any API to integrate with Pinterest.
Let me know if you have any idea for integration with Pinterest.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need to use the Pin it Button, but you can, of course. you can also implement on an onClick event something like this:

```
PinIt pinIt = new PinIt();
pinIt.setImageUri(imageUri);
PinIt.setPartnerId(PINTEREST_CLIENT_ID);

    //Content description
    pinIt.setDescription(description);
    // URL to share
    pinIt.setUrl(pageUrl);

    pinIt.setListener(new PinItListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(boolean completed) {
            if(completed) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Shared to Pinterest!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Share Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Also be careful to remember that they don't accept redirecting or shortened URLs.

Hope this helps

Comment: it doesnt work for me, actually toast display earlier..

Answer (score 1):

**Pinterest** `Api` provides two way for pinning image to **Pinterest**. By **Link** or By using **Uri** from app.

First you have to create a **PinItButton** using their sdk then you can set the image link or uri

```
PinItButton.setPartnerId("1432292"); // -- your app id --
RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.v);
pinIt = new PinItButton(this);
view.addView(pinIt);
pinIt.setImageUri(Uri.parse(pictureUri)); // uri of picture
pinIt.setDescription("shared via PinIt");
```

Comment: How do you actually pin it though?